# Couldn't Excute command line PostGIS pgsql2shp

Tags: postgis, command-line, pgsql2shp

I am using postgres 9.3 with postgis 2.1 on Ubuntu 14. When I tried to dump pgsql table using pgsql2shp, I get the following error.

```
Error: pg_wrapper: pgsql2shp was not found in /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin
```

The command I used is the following.

```
pgsql2shp -f "/home/user/testshp.shp" -h localhost -u postgres -P postgres  dbname "SELECT * FROM table"
```

In  `sudo nano /etc/environment` I have added,`:/usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp`

I also also created a link using a guide from [here](https://geekforum.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/install-and-run-postgresql-postgis-and-opengeo/).

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/raster2pgsql
```

Is any the things I did causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was all about the **unneeded** symbolic link.

```
 sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp
```

I fixed the issue finally by just removing the symbolic links.

```
 sudo rm /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql
 sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp
 sudo rm /usr/local/bin/raster2pgsql
```

Then removed postgis 2.1 with

```
 sudo apt-get remove postgis-2.1
 sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1
```

Then installed postgis again by

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
 sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get install postgis
```

Comment: Looks like you had installed postgis for postgresql 9.4 while running postgresql 9.3.

Comment: Yes, that could be one of the problems too.